# pivot cache using vba getting run time error

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, excel-2007, excel-2016

I have created one script which is running perfectly fine in my laptop but while my colleague is trying with same script getting error with pivot cache

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=1, SourceData:=range("A1:AV" & LastRow))
```

```
Sub pivot_qty()
    
    Dim PCache As PivotCache, LastRow As Long, pt As PivotTable
    
    
      'If "Pivot" worksheet already exists, delete it
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Pivot qty").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
     LastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
       
    
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
     Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=1, SourceData:=range("A1:AV" & LastRow))
         Worksheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot qty"
     Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PCache, TableDestination:=range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable1")
     
     'Select fields for PivotTable
         ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
      
        With pt.PivotFields("Plant")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        
         With pt.PivotFields("Service Desc")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With
        
        
         With pt.PivotFields("Price Per Unit")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 3
        End With
         
     ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
         
End Sub
```

Comment: A guess is that the use of `Range` on that line of not qualified. However, call you confirm the error number and exact error text?

Comment: @JohnM im getting error 438 , object doesnt support this proprty

Comment: See the MS Docs for [PivotCaches.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create) which say "When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly"